# Stack Overflow error when constructing a new object in Java

Tags: java, object, stack-overflow

I'm trying to construct a PackingCase object with a certain set of values. While the program shows no errors during coding, when running, I get this error;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at assignment.pkg2.PackingCase.<init>(PackingCase.java:59)
at assignment.pkg2.PackingCase.<init>(PackingCase.java:60)
```

My code is as follows;

```
public class PackingCase {
// private fields go here

int serialNumber;
int timesUsed;
int timeCreated;
int timeStored;
String name;
String description;


void setCase(int s, int TU, int TC, int TS){
    serialNumber = s;
    timesUsed = TU;
    timeCreated = TC;
    timeStored = TS;

}

double volume(){
    return serialNumber*timesUsed*timeCreated*timeStored;
}

public PackingCase(){ 
    PackingCase PC1 = new PackingCase();
    double vol;

    PC1.setCase(1, 2, 3, 4);

    vol = PC1.volume();
    System.out.println(""+vol);




}
```

Line 59 is "public PackingCase(){" , and Line 60 is "PackingCase PC1 = new PackingCase();". I have no idea what's going on, considering that an example I found uses virtually the same code structure, and compiles with no errors whatever. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: +1: stack overflow error message

Answer (score 10):

Each creation of a new object leads to the creation of another new object (and so on...) until the stack is overflowed.

Instead, it should be look like that:

```
public PackingCase(){ 
    this.setCase(1, 2, 3, 4);
    vol = this.volume();
    System.out.println(""+vol);
}
```

Comment: @pst - pedantic doesn't need to be followed by "but...". Thanks!]

Answer (score 3):

You have a recursive call in the constructor. Leave the constructor empty (simply delete it) and run this code from `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] a){
    PackingCase pc1 = new PackingCase();
    pc1.setCase(1, 2, 3, 4);
    double vol = pc1.volume();
    System.out.println(""+vol);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public PackingCase(){      PackingCase PC1 = new PackingCase(); ...}
```

Constructor recursively calls itself, causing stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `new` within the handler for `new`, creating an infinite loop (and since the stack is finite, it eventually runs out of space). But `public PackingCase() { ... }` is a *constructor*. That means it is only called when someone has already used `new PackingCase()`. The code within the constructor doesn't have to create the object (allocate space), just initialize it (set values for its fields).